# iDVD Random Transitions

Tags: macos, applescript, slideshow

I am creating a dvd slide show using iDVD and I see how to add transtions manually but what I would like to do is have iDVD insert random transitions for me.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite likely to be possible using AppleScript

At a guess it would involve Add slideshow

You would need to load up the iDVD dictionary in the AppleScript editor

Comment: Thanks I will explore your suggestion.  For now I have created my slide show in iPhoto, letting it handle the transitions and then exported it, then used that in iDvd.

Thanks again